# What is a WCF Service Moniker?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, unmanaged

This maybe a stupid question but I have googled my butt off trying to find a definition of "Service Moniker". I see it everywhere with respect to WCF; it gets used, it gets configured, etc. At first I thought it might be some tool, then some object, and now I am beginning to believe that it is just a set of parameters describing the WCF channel.

I have got a simple WCF service (with callbacks) and client working using a named pipes communication channel in the past two weeks and for all I know I am 'using' a 'service moniker'.

Could someone please tell me what a service moniker is? That may help me toward trying to solve my next problem of accessing my WCF service from an UNMANAGED C++ client; I see the term a lot in articles related to the C++/WCF issue.

Big thanks!!

Comment: Did this section on MSDN not help? [Integrating with COM Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733928%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That site is one of the first I looked at and is part of the frustration. They say one must 'configure' a moniker and show examples of 'service moniker strings' and state that after one does these set of things that one can use the 'service moniker' but never say what it is. I am sure its not the 'ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool' and its probably not the string with the channel connection information. Is it (your service name).exe.config? Is it the internal file generated when on adds a service reference say to the client project?

Answer (score 0):

This is to communicate legacy com applications. For more details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733885%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/using-the-wcf-service-moniker-to-communicate-between-legacy-com-applications-and-new-net-applications/
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wcf/article.php/c18455/Using-the-WCF-Service-Moniker-to-Communicate-Between-Legacy-COM-Apps-and-New-NET-Framework-Apps.htm

Comment: The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733885%28v=vs.110%29.aspx site I have already seen. It does not help. It still does not say what the 'service moniker' is. Is it the assemblies? It is the code I write to implement a WCF service which can then be hosted (and is thus the entire package)? I will look at the other URLs later.

Comment: Its a component. You can see an example from this link : http://jegatech.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/calling-wcf-service-inside-ms-office-applications/ http://geekswithblogs.net/cicorias/archive/2007/08/28/Consuming-WCF-Services-from-COM-using-C.aspx